# How to populate 2 CachedRowSet with the same ResultSet?

Tags: java, database, oracle, resultset, cachedrowset

I need help with duplicating a `ResultSet` using `CachedRowSet` or any other way possible. I'm at this point

```
ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);

CachedRowSetImpl crs = new CachedRowSetImpl();
crs.populate(rs);
```

How would one populate a different `CachedRowSet`, say `crs2`, with the `ResultSet` `rs`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to do a deep copy try

```
CachedRowSet crs2 = crs.createCopy();
```